# Finding values of constants for which 1st and 2nd order derivatives of a function vanish

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization, physics

I'm trying to find critical values of some constants $v_c$ and $T_c$, for which holds the equality below:
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}\bigg)\biggr\rvert_{v=v_c,\;  T=T_c}=0,\quad \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial v^2}\bigg)\biggr\rvert_{v=v_c,\;  T=T_c}=0$$
Here is the code (please notice that `Thawk` is the temperature $T$ in my code):

```
Clear[rplus, c2, M, \[Alpha], Thawk, \[CapitalLambda], rscale, c6, \
c7, M, rplus, P]
\[CapitalLambda] = -8 \[Pi]*P
c6 = 10
c7 = 0.1
c8 = 0.00001
rscale = 10
c2 = 0.00001
M = (9 rplus - c2 \[Alpha])/(18 + 24 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2) - (
  rplus^3 \[CapitalLambda])/6
rplus = v/2
\[Alpha] = 0.1
sol = Solve[
  Thawk == -(-(1/(
        81 M rplus^2))(3 (3 M + 2 c8 \[Alpha]^2) (c2 \[Alpha] + 
             6 M (3 + 4 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2)) - 
          18 M rplus^3 (3 + 
             4 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2) \[CapitalLambda] + 
          2 c8 \[Alpha]^2 (c2 \[Alpha] + 
             6 M (3 + 4 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2) - 
             2 rplus^3 (3 + 
                4 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2) \[CapitalLambda]) Log[(
            rscale^2 (c2 \[Alpha] + 6 M (3 + 4 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2) +
                rplus^3 (3 + 
                  4 (c6 - c7) \[Alpha]^2) \[CapitalLambda]))/(
            9 rplus^3)]))/4 \[Pi], P
  ]
P[v_] = P /. sol[[1]]

NSolve[{D[P[v], v] == 0, D[P[v], {v, 2}] == 0}, {Thawk, v}]
```

Pressure $P$ is stored within the $\Lambda$ constant, which is defined at the beginning of my code and $v$ is stored in `rplus`. Unfortunately, it seems that this piece of code does not work properly. Maybe someone has suggestions on how to obtain critical values?

Comment: Are you sure you want `sol[[1]]` and not `sol[[2]]`? Perhaps use something like `Block[{Thawk=100},LogLogPlot[Abs[P[v]],{v,0.001,10}]]` to see if `sol[[1]]` or `sol[[2]]` matches your expectation, and also check the sign of `P[v]`. Do you have an order of magnitude estimate for the values `Thawk` and `v`? What would be typical values?

Comment: Yeas, I meant sol[[2]]. Order for `Thawk` is something around 0-10, same for `v`

Comment: You should edit your question if you want `sol[[2]]`. If one plots `P[v]` for different fixed values of `Thawk`, one can see a maximum where `P'[v]==0`, but it seems that the second derivative `P''[v]` is always negative there. Can you comment on that, and are you sure there is a solution?